# Meta title W3C Validation Error with

Tags: themes, post-meta, validation, html

On the single post, the WordPress generates the meta title automatically but it gives validation error.

This is what WordPress generates:

```
<meta name="title" content="The post title goes here"  />
```

And this is the error I get:

**Bad value title for attribute name on element meta: Keyword title is not registered.**

How can this be fixed?
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`title` is not part of the current HTML5 spec for meta element names. See [here](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/semantics.html#standard-metadata-names). The `<title>` element in the document head should be enough for metadata purposes.

Comment: Thanks, but then how can I remove it? I cannot see the code which generates it. I think wp_head() generates it.

Comment: Look in the header.php file in the template you're using. Failing that, look for functions in your template that are registered to the wp_head action.